# If $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ and $a \neq 0$ then for the system of quadratic equations in n variables $x_1, x_2 ... x_n$

Tags: polynomials

> If $a,b,c  \in \mathbb R$ and $a \neq 0$ then for the system of quadratic equations in n variables $x_1, x_2 ... x_n$ 
> $ax_1^2+bx_1+c=x_2$ 
> $ax_2^2+bx_2+c=x_3$
> . 
> . 
> . 
> $ax_n^2+bx_n+c=x_1$ 
> $1)$ show that that the equations have no solutions if $(b-1)^2<4ac$ 
> $2)$ find the solutions if $(b-1)^2>4ac$

My Attempt:

I was able to do the first part by adding all the equations and converting them into summations of quadratic equations,

$$ax_1^2+x_1(b-1)+c + ax_2^2+x_2(b-1)+c ... ax_n^2+x_n(b-1) + c=0$$

for this to have no solution, $(b-1)^2<4ac$

But, how do you find the solutions if there are any (for the condition $(b-1)^2>4ac$)
One thing that can be done is just to substitute and then solve the resulting $f(x^{2n})$ polynomial. But that would be too much work. Is there any other easier way to find the solutions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the system by setting $y_i=ax_i+\frac{b}2$ so that
$$
y_{(i+1)\bmod n}=ax_{(i+1)\bmod n}+\frac{b}2
=a^2x_i^2+abx_i+ac+\frac{b}2
=y_i^2+ac+\frac{b}2-\frac{b^2}4
=y_i^2+\tilde c
$$
so that in the end there is only one free parameter determining the dynamic of the map. This map is well-known, you are looking for period-$n$ cycles of the Mandelbrot map on the real line. This can also be transformed to cycles of the Feigenbaum/logistic map.

Comment: [+1] thorough analysis

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I think one trick is to realize that the cyclic permutation $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ yields the same system. Therefore there is a solution with $x_1=x_2=\ldots{}=x_n$. Then you end up with just one equation $ax^2+(b-1)x+c=0$ which is easily solvable.

**Edit 2**

One can write the system as follows: $x_{i+i}=ax_i+bx+c$ and take the subscripts$\mod n$. This leads to a [quadratic map](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html). According to that website there are (at least for certain $a,b,c$) not only period 2 (as already given in the comments) but also period 3 fixed point, which means that there are solutions for $n=3$ where all $x_i$ are distinct. (In fact, there are such solutions for every $n$.) I tried to find a solution for $(a,b,c)=(1,0,-1)$ and $n=3$. This leads to the map $x_{i+i}=f(x_i)=x_i^2-1$. Its period 3 fixed point $x$ satisfies $f(f(f(x)))-x=0$ which leads to finding the roots of an eighth degree polynomial. Dividing the polynomial $f(x)-x=x^2-x-1$ which is satisfied by the (period one) fixed point the polynomial $x^6+x^5-2x^4-x^3+x^2+1$ remains. (The Wolfram page says $\ldots -x^2 \ldots$ which is wrong). However, this polynomial only has non-real roots. Therefore, for the parameters given there is no solution except for the one given in the first part.

Comment: Your argument is incorrect because you are assuming the system must have a single solution$$a=1,b=0,c=-1,n=2$$Gives $(x_1,x_2)=(0,-1)$

Comment: -1 because of the objections in the comments

Comment: @yukelid Okay your solution is correct. But can you elaborate where my error is? Does my argument at least hold for $n\geq3$

Comment: @diffset I agree that the cyclic permutation $(1,2,…,n)$ must also be a solution, but this doesn't mean that $x_1=x_2=…=x_n$ must hold; it is one of many possibilities. As for $n≥3$, $$a=1,b=0,c=−1,n=4$$ again gives $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(0,−1,0,-1)$.

Comment: @yukelid Thanks! But can you come up with a solution for odd $n>1$ where $x_i\neq x_j$ for some $i\neq j$? :-)

Comment: @miracle173 Maybe you want to reconsider after having seen my edits?

Comment: @yukelid You won't find a solution for $(a,b,c,n)=(1,0,-1,3)$. See my edit.

Comment: @diffset i agree, but what are you trying to arrive at with all the case-verification?